# Change TextBox text and focus via CheckBox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I **check** or **uncheck** a `CheckBox`, I want to clear the `TextBox` and set focus. I implemented it using code-behind.

My xmal:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkbox1" Checked="checkbox1_Checked" Unchecked="checkbox1_Checked" />
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Text="Hello" />
```

My C#:

```
private void checkbox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Text = "";
    textbox1.Focus();
}
```

Is it possible to do it all in XAML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use data triggers. They work by creating a binding to a regular property, which is then 
monitored for changes.

For instance, consider the following example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Styles.StyleDataTriggerSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="StyleDataTriggerSample" Height="200" Width="200">

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <CheckBox Name="cbSample" Content="Hello, world?" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="48">

            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbSample, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes!" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>

        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In this example, we have a CheckBox and a TextBlock. Using a DataTrigger, we bind the TextBlock 
to the IsChecked property of the CheckBox. We then supply a default style, where the text 
is "No" and the foreground colour is red, and then, using a DataTrigger, we supply a style for 
when the IsChecked property of the CheckBox is changed to True, in which case we make it 
green with a text saying "Yes!" (as seen on the screen shot).

you can find more in [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger).